# BigQuery join too slow for a table of small size

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table with the following details:
- Table Size    39.6 MB
- Number of Rows    691,562
- 2 columns : contact_guid  STRING, program_completed STRING
- column 1 data type is like uuid . around 30 char length
- column 2 data type is string with around 50 char length

I am trying this query:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  cp1.contact_guid AS p1,
  cp2.contact_guid AS p2,
  COUNT(*) AS cnt
FROM
  `data.contact_pairs_program_together`  cp1
JOIN
  `data.contact_pairs_program_together`  cp2
ON
  cp1.program_completed=cp2.program_completed
WHERE
  cp1.contact_guid < cp2.contact_guid
GROUP BY
  cp1.contact_guid,
  cp2.contact_guid having cnt >1 order by cnt desc
```

Time taken to execute: 1200 secs

I know I am doing a self join and it is mentioned in best practices to avoid self join.

My Questions:

1. I feel this table size in terms of mb is too small for BigQuery therefore why is it taking so much time? And what does small table mean for BigQuery in context of join in terms of number of rows and size in bytes?
2. Is the number of rows too large? 700k ^ 2 is 10^11 rows during join. What would be a realistic number of rows for joins?
3. I did check the documentation regarding joins, but did not find much regarding how big a table can be for joins and how much time can be expected for it to run. How do we estimate rough execution time?

Execution Details:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think BigQuery lets you add an index, which is what might really help in your query.  Your table is almost one million records; the running time does not surprise me.

Comment: 1) Can you post the execution timeline that your "details" tab shows after running the query? 2) Can you try to JOIN ... ON .. AND, instead of JOIN ... ON ... WHERE?

Comment: @FelipeHoffa I have added execution timeline. Will update on the alternative you suggested.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I get that it is almost 1 million records but the table size is too small. Just wondering away joins have to be used in Bigquery without indexes and usually we will have table with these many rows. What is the method to get the query working or atleast get rough estimates about execution time. I am totally confused.

Comment: The only suggestion I can make is to see if you can rephrase your query using analytic functions.  This might give you a peformance boost.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Understood. But what would be the process to rephrase the query? If I understand this then I can rewrite queries knowing what kind of querying styles to avoid.

Comment: I can't see an obvious way.  Maybe if you add some sample data to your question, someone will see a way.  In the meantime, I have upvoted you.

Comment: @FelipeHoffa  Query complete (1338.9s elapsed, 39.6 MB processed) after changing to " t1 JOIN t2 ON ... AND  ..."

Comment: The query doesn't really make sense. What is the purpose of the WHERE clause? What is the count supposed to be? Providing sample input data and expected output would be useful. Using analytic functions would be a much better idea.

Comment: @ElliottBrossard About the WHERE clause, say if column contains records a,b then want to avoid (a,a),(b,b) and (b,a) is same as (a,b) as relation is commutative. Regarding the problem statement it can thought of as column 1 is say student_id and column 2 is id of the course he has taken with year(Eg. CS101_2000_Spring). Now we want to find pairs of students who have taken some courses together and that count for the pair is more than 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As shown on the screenshot you provided - you are dealing with an exploding join.

In this case step 3 takes 1.3 million rows, and manages to produce 459 million rows. Steps 04 to 0B deal with repartitioning and re-shuffling all that extra data - as the query didn't provision enough resources to deal with these number of rows: It scaled up from 1 parallel input to 10,000!

You have 2 choices here: Either avoid exploding joins, or assume that exploding joins will take a long time to run. But as explained in the question - you already knew that!

How about if you generate all the extra rows in one op (do the join, materialize) and then run another query to process the 459 million rows? The first query will be slow for the reasons explained, but the second one will run quickly as BigQuery will provision enough resource to deal with that amount of data.

Comment: I think joining is needed for the usecase. But got to know that analytic functions can do similar things. Regarding join, materialize and then another query, I think I get it. Initially data was just ~40mb so bigquery provisioned some resource whereas if join was materialized then join table would be around 43GB and now if we run the query, bigquery will provision more resources and should be much faster. But I will be charged for 43GB scan instead of 40MB. That is the trade off. Am I right? In another answer, analytic functions was used.Could you tell if that is better than join in this case?

Comment: I tried to materialize the join and it worked faster. 
Without materializing:::Query complete (1337.4s elapsed, 39.6 MB processed). 
Using Materialized join::: 
join cmd: Query complete (303.9s elapsed, 39.6 MB processed) . 
group by cmd: Query complete (31.6s elapsed, 24.0 GB processed). 

It is 24GB instead of 43GB because the screenshot result had a string agg in the query. So the conclusion is materialized join works faster but we get charged for the extra bytes for the materialized join table. Thank you Felipe. Hope I understood correctly. Plz correct me in case I got it wrongly.

Answer (score 1):

Agree with below suggestions

> see if you can rephrase your query using analytic functions (by Tim)

> Using analytic functions would be a much better idea (by Elliott)

Below is how I would make it

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT
  p1, p2, COUNT(1) AS cnt
FROM (
  SELECT
    contact_guid AS p1, 
    ARRAY_AGG(contact_guid) OVER(my_win) guids
  FROM `data.contact_pairs_program_together` 
  WINDOW my_win AS (
    PARTITION BY program_completed 
    ORDER BY contact_guid DESC 
    RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING
  )
), UNNEST(guids) p2
GROUP BY p1, p2
HAVING cnt > 1
ORDER BY cnt DESC
```

Please try and let us know if helped

Comment: Trying to execute but facing the following error.
Error: ORDER BY key must be numeric in a RANGE-based window with OFFSET PRECEDING or OFFSET FOLLOWING boundaries, but has type STRING at [11:5]

Comment: that's true I thought of number here. Ok. so if it is a string and called GUID - I would assume it is unique so you can replace `RANGE` with `ROWS`  - try and let me know if this helped

Comment: Executed and it took "Query complete (1197.7s elapsed, 39.6 MB processed)". Similar time. My question is if we join two tables with say 1m rows, is it to be understood that it will take this much amount of time and is reasonable. Why I ask is I would like to know what criteria will make query run faster(reduce by 1/3 or 1/2). Are analytic functions the right choice for these kinds of queries? Thank you for the quick response :) .

Comment: in general - when possible using analytics functions is preferable over joining

Comment: Output of self join query(1,986,138 rows) and output using this analytical version(2,000,599 rows) is different. Any idea or pointers why this difference in number of rows in the output?

Comment: I would recommend to isolate/identify those extra rows and see if they are valid or not. Next will depend on outcome of this check. If you will share result of this check - will be great

Comment: Ok. I shall try to isolate and update you. But will take a while.